# what does `a: b` statement do in python?

Tags: python

I was modifying a dictionary, and accidentally wrote something like

```
data = dict(a=1, b=2)
if condition:
    data['c']: 3
```

I expected this to be a syntax error, however it runs correctly, and the statement simply seems to have no effect.

Which makes me curious: what kind of statement is this, and why is this legal?

Comment: They're called type annotations. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#specification

Comment: I get a syntax error at the colon symbol when I execute it.

Comment: @roganjosh: thanks, this seems to be it.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé presumably you have a version of Python < 3.6

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé: I'm on python 3.6

Comment: @blue_note FWIW "python dictionary assignment by colon" in Google was what I searched to get that, and I wasn't immediately aware of the answer from the question